# SharePoint Online - Open PDF in new tab

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, pdf

I'm currently setting my document library to open all Word, Excel, PPT and PDF using the client application.

But for some reason PDF won't open up in a new tab in the browser.

Are there any workarounds for this to make this work?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: So, you want to open PDF in browser?  Currently, if you open a PDF file, what will it use to open?

Comment: Hi Kally_MSFT,
Currently it open in the same window in the browser. I want it to open in a new tab.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce this issue on my environment, it seems to be by default when opening a PDF file, it will open in the same tab instead of a new tab.

As a workaround, I suggest you use "Open in browser" instead of clicking the file name directly.
[image]

Besides, there is an similar feedback about this issue, you can vote [the feedback](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/da0f7361-d890-ec11-a81b-0022484ddce7)

Comment: Thanks Kally.
I had a workaround for it using column formatting with json just for pdf file and it works

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, if possible, please share your JSON code here, so that other who may meet this similar issue could benefit from it. :)